# Gnome 3 and compiz, everything works except Explode and Leaf Spread animations

Tags: 11.10, gnome, compiz, animations

I am using 11.10 with Gnome 3, I have installed Compiz, and have got it functioning *almost* how I want it. I want my windows to Leaf Spread, which seems to work fine for a few minutes after I enable it and restart my machine. However, over the time of a few window closes, I notice that the objects are not showing up little by little until the Leaf Spread just doesn't show at all? This really isn't a big deal, but I'd like things to work properly. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Leaf spread is actually meant for opening windows. Currently, there is no solution for this, but I would suggest you use the Burn option for closing window and Glide 3 for opening one.